# Why would this INSERT query insert a time value, rather than a date?

Tags: date, ms-access, insert, vb6

I have a field in an `MS-Access` database that is shown below.

[image]

When I run this query on the database (from a VB6 application or directly as a query)

```
INSERT INTO [stockQuantities] ([stockCode], [description], [productGroup], [qtyFrom], " & _
"[price], [dateQuoted]) VALUES (" SOS ", "SOS SAND FOR COSTING ONLY", "COS", 10, " & _
"6.34, 01/12/2018);
```

The final value, for `dateQuoted` is instead inserting as 00:00:04. When I change the format to `Short Date`, it inserts as 30/12/1899.

Why is my date not inserting in the correct format? Is it the query or the field that's the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dates in Access SQL need to be delimited by octothorpes, and in either mm/dd/yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd format.

Your query should look like this (assuming you want to insert the first of December):

```
INSERT INTO [stockQuantities] ([stockCode], [description], [productGroup], [qtyFrom], " & _
"[price], [dateQuoted]) VALUES (" SOS ", "SOS SAND FOR COSTING ONLY", "COS", 10, " & _
"6.34, #12/01/2018#);
```

However, you're also allowed to insert a numerical value, which is the value in days offset from 1899-12-30. Your insert query just inserted 1 divided by 12 divided by 2018, which is a value of 4.388E-05 , and that corresponds to 4 seconds from Access's reference date.

If the date for a date-time column is equal to the reference date, Access only displays the time portion.

Comment: That's certainly more information than I was expecting, at least now I understand why it's not working correctly, though! Thanks, I'll correct the code - Merry Christmas!

Comment: Yay octothorpes!